# Retain a value obtained inside promise - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When the page loads, the dropdown is bound with some values (say 1, 2...7)
Based on a condition, I would like to set its selected value. When set inside a promise it isn't working. How to solve this.

**html:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <select id="ddlSets" data-ng-model="SetId">
   <option value="0">-- Select Set --</option>
   <option data-ng-repeat="item in Sets" value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Code}}</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

**ctrl.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl",["$scope","Factory",function($scope,Factory){   


     var init = function(){
      //$scope.Sets = (code here to bind data to the dropdown)

      var promise = Factory.GetSetId();
      promise.then(function (success) {
          if (success.data == 5) {
            $scope.SetId = 5; //value isn't set. It remains 0.
          }
       },
       function (error) {
         console.log(error);
      });
    }
    //it works if set here - $scope.SetId = 7;

            init();
  }]);
```

**factory.js:**

```
app.factory("Factory", ["$http",function ($http) {
var factory = {};
factory.GetSetId = function () {
        return $http({
            url: "http://localhost:12345.asmx/GetSetId",
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function (data, status) {
        }).error(function (data, status) {
        });        
    }
return factory;
}]);
```

Comment: Can you make a plunker that shows this behaviour?

Comment: dont know how to do it with promise/$http. Will it be ok if I just create one with the code

Comment: If it doesn't actually demonstrate the issue, then there isn't much point to it! Perhaps a separate SO question could help with that if you're stuck.

Comment: I fixed it by writing `<option data-ng-repeat="item in Sets" value="{{item.Id}}" ng-selected="item.Id==SetId">{{item.Code}}</option>`

Answer (score 2):

Change your html to following. Use scope variable without $scope in html.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <select id="ddlSets" data-ng-model="SetId">
   <option value="0">-- Select Set --</option>
   <option data-ng-repeat="item in Sets" ng-value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Code}}</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep. Also worth noting that the default option should not have a value `<option value="">-- Select Set --</option>`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.Issue remains. why should the default not have a value. I have tasks based on the 0 value too.

Comment: use ng-value instead of value. Edited my answer.

Comment: No luck. It works if i manually set it outside the promise even without ng-value

Comment: Then I have doubt that your promise is not getting execute. are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes pretty sure. I have an alert inside promise which pops success.data as 5

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to assign a value to a property of a object like:

controller:

```
$scope.model = {};
var promise = Factory.GetSetId();
promise.then(function (success) {
  if (success.data == 5) {
    $scope.model.SetId = 5; //update
  }
},
function (error) {
 console.log(error);
});
```

template:

```
<select id="ddlSets" data-ng-model="model.SetId">
```

Comment: have you alert the value this time?

Comment: Yes alert pops the value but it is not set as selected value to the dropdown

Comment: you can print it {{model.SetId}} on page to test if the value is really not retained or the select syntax isn't correct.

Comment: If i print it, works fine. But not selected in dropdown. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: i think you should check the dropdown grammer in angular, or try dynamic select without ajax, maybe change the selection by input box vlaue

Comment: i don't know if it works, try add a pre-defined value for SetId like: $scope.model = {SetId: null};

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$scope.SetId` is `5`, a number, but the options element has a value of `"5"`, evaluated from `{{item.Id}}`, which is a string since interpolation of `{{ }}` always gives a string.

(Not that `"5"`, doesn't actually include the quotes in the string, but I just include them here to try to show the data type).

So you have 2 options.

1. Use `ngOptions` to generate the `options` elements. Something like the following should work.

   ```
   <select id="ddlSets" data-ng-model="SetId" ng-options="item.Id as item.Code for item in Sets">
     <option value="0">-- Select Set --</option>
   </select>
   ```
2. Only use string ids in the scope. A quick and dirty way would be to convert it to a string before setting it in the scope.

   ```
   if (success.data == 5) {
     $scope.SetId = 5 + '';
   }
   ```

Comment: I dont think thats the problem, cause, when I say `$scope.SetId=7;`, outside the promise, it works.

Comment: @Qwerty Ah: I missed that!

Comment: Its' ok. This isn't the first time I faced this. I just left it before. How can we assign a value to a variable inside promises and retain them even after that. Seems so hard. Should the way, the factory code is written be changed ???